# Transferring a NSString to a UILabel using storyboard segues

Tags: ios, storyboard, segue

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
   NSLog(@"prepareForSegue: %@", segue.identifier);
   if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"returnText"])
   {   
      [segue.destinationViewController setText:@"New String"];
   }
}


-(void)setText:(NSString*)transferString;
{
   NSString* result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", transferString];
   NSLog(@"Got transfer %@", result);
   //Prints correct string
   LabelText.text=result;
   NSLog(@"Labeltext %@\n",LabelText.text);
   //NSLog outputs null
   //Doesn’t update the label
 }
```

I want the label to update with the new text after switching...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
// In your destination controller .h file
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *transferStr;

// In your destination controller .m file
@synthesize transferStr;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.LabelText.text = self.transferStr;
}

// In your first controller .m file
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
   NSLog(@"prepareForSegue: %@", segue.identifier);
   if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"returnText"])
   {   
      [segue.destinationViewController setTransferStr:@"New String"];
   }
}
```

Tested and working...

Don't forget though to include the destination controller's .h file in your first controller.

The problem is probably that the UILabel is not instantiated yet when the prepareForSegue method is called, that's why it is null at that specific time...

Comment: Works great... I don’t understand how “setTransferStr” gets defined is all.  I appreciate the help.

Comment: Every time you define a property on a class, two methods generated automatically for you (known as getter / setter methods). The getter is simply the name of the property (like: `-(NSString*)transferStr`) the setter though begins always with the word `set` and the name of the property with the first letter in capital (so... `setTransferStr`). For more on properties [see Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html). Also if this answer was what you were looking for, consider marking it as correct.